# Android deploy for release problem

Tags: android, publishing, facebook-android-sdk

Hello i have a problem when make release apk to upload to market
There is a facebook integration in my application, use android facebook sdk. It work great in development time, both simulator and real device (HTC Wildfire and HTC Desire, device apk built used debug.keystore which auto gen by android sdk)

When i gen a release keystore to release by keytool like on android developer site and export apk with this keystore, app no longer work, I still can open app but first screen need login via facebook, app always fail to connect as soon as facebook connecting screen appear.

Can some one please help me
Thanks

Comment: How does it fail? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I am getting the same issue.. Any solutions or reasons for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just generate the hash again using your release key.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore /path/to/your.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: make sure you alias key exactly, you can see it by command type: keytool -list -v -keystore path_to_your_key